# What is ma'amad sh'loshtan and where in Rambam is it defined?

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam, transactions

In [Sheluchin veShuttafin 3:7](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1363723/jewish/Sheluchin-veShuttafin-Chapter-Three.htm) (also other places in Rambam) ma'amad sh'loshtan is mentioned

> The only way a person can transfer ownership of a debt is through a
> ma'amad sh'loshtan - which is a dictate whose rationale cannot be
> explained

I searched on Chabad's website, on Sefaria but no Torah text definition was returned. In a secular law [book](https://vdoc.pub/download/critical-studies-in-ancient-law-comparative-law-and-legal-history-2baebok9m9b0) this definition is given

> Other exceptions are ma'amad sh'loshtan, the transfer of an obligation
> toward a creditor from a debtor to his own debtor, done orally in the
> presence of all three

Comment: Are you aware that it appears in the Gemara several time throughout shas? I.e. the search begins before Rambam.

Comment: That's interesting. "through a _ma'amad sh'loshtan_" is R. Eliyahu Touger's transl[iter]ation of "במעמד שלושתן". Of the [other places where "במעמד שלושתן" comes up](https://www.chabad.org/search/results.asp?searchWord=%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%9E%D6%B7%D7%A2%D6%B2%D7%9E%D6%B7%D7%93+%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B0%D7%9C%D6%B8%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%9F), in [Malveh veLoveh 16:4](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1159455/jewish/Malveh-veLoveh-Chapter-16.htm#v4), he translates it as "in the presence of the three of them"...

Comment: ...and in [Ishut 5:17](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/952879/jewish/Ishut-Chapter-Five.htm#v17) as "in the presence of the third party" (see [footnote 23](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/952879/jewish/Ishut-Chapter-Five.htm#footnote23a952879) there). I'd say that Rambam didn't define the term, because he meant it simply as "in the presence of those three"...

Comment: ...I'm guessing the translator explained the transliterated term in the footnotes in [his book](https://moznaim.com/collections/english/products/mishneh-torah-rambam), but those weren't copied over to chabad.org for this chapter (and others).

Answer (score 0):

H/t @Dov for the pointer. [BT Gittin 13](https://www.dafyomi.co.il/gitin/points/gi-ps-013.htm) explains

> MA'AMAD SHELOSHTAM
>
> (a) (Rav): If Levi says to Yehudah 'you have money of mine. Give it to
> David', and all three are present, David acquires the money.
>
> (b) (Rava): Presumably, Rav's law applies only to a deposit (because
> he could give it over), but not to a loan. However, Rav actually said
> it even about a loan!
>
> 1. (Shmuel): If Levi says to Yehudah 'you borrowed money from me. Give it to David', and all three are present, Yehudah owes the money to
>    David.
>
> (c) Question: Why does this work?
>
> (d) Answer #1 (Ameimar): It is as if Yehudah said when he borrowed the
> money 'I am indebted to you, or anyone who will come in your stead.'
>
> (e) Objection (Rav Ashi): If so, it should not be possible to give the
> loan to someone who was not born at the time the loan was given!
>
> 1. Even R. Meir, who says that one can transfer ownership of something that did not come to the world, allows transferring only to someone in
>    the world!